# Bansuri 1/2 open Ma vs full open Ma

Tags: notation, scales, indian-classical, bansuri

In Bansuri notation, Ma is half open or fully open.

Which octave is half open Ma located and which octave is full open Ma located.

Or is full open Ma a special case?

Different places tell different things.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full open `Ma` is not a special case. Full open `Ma` is just a sharp (`F#`). Half open `Ma` is not sharp, but a natural (`F`). Some websites put different things, but here is the standard chart I recommend you use:

[image: Bansuri Fingering Chart]